# _crashlytics.default.log is not a function

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase

I followed the docs on [crashlytics/quick-start](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/crashlytics/quick-start) with autolink, using react-native 0.60.5.

Using the code below (exact copy from docs), I got `_crashlytics.default.log is not a function`.

```
import crashlytics from '@react-native-firebase/crashlytics';

function forceCrash() {
    crashlytics.log('Testing crash');
    crashlytics.crash();
}
```

I'm trying to think that I don't need change any file on /android/ folder.

The project source code is on [github repo](https://github.com/TiagoGouvea/battery-life-monitor/tree/react-native-firebase-setup).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a mistake in the documentation which has been fixed and will be live soon. Correct usage should be:

```
crashlytics().log('...');
crashlytics().crash();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! But... I didn't receive any log on crashlytics panel, it still empty.

Comment: Updates to the console are not realtime, they can take a number of hours to appear. Let me know whether they come up or not after 24 hours or so!

Comment: It didn't. It still empty. I try the `log`, `crash` and the `recordError too.. but, none appears on my panel.